# auto and delctype(auto) type deduction example

Tags: c++, auto, decltype

I read an article about `auto` type deduction with `decltype` and I am wondering if my logic is correct about how type is deduced in the example below (so if I am mistaken please correct me :)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Widget
{
public:
    Widget() = default;
};

int main()
{
    Widget w;
    const Widget& cw = w;          // cw is const Widget&
    auto myWidget1 = cw;           // (1) myWidget1  is Widget
    decltype(auto) myWidget2 = cw; // (2) myWidget2 is const Widget&
}
```

So far what I understood is that :

**for 1** : the auto type deduction is used and in this case it is like temlpate type deduction for parms passed by value. Which means the cv-qualifiers and refs are ignored which will result in `Widget` as type in the end.

**for 2**: the decltype is used and then passed to auto what really is `cw` a const Widget& and then all are set and the type is const Widget&.

So is what I wrote/understood right or wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: `const auto& myWidget2 = cw;` will also get you a `const Widget&`. Often the exact type doesnt matter, but constness and whether it is a reference or value almost always does ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a trick, so you can make the compiler to print a type:

```
template <typename>
struct TD;
```

Then use:

```
TD<decltype(myWidget1)>();
```

As `TD<...>` is an incomplete type, the compiler will complain, and will print your type in the error message:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type `struct TD<Widget>`

So `myWidget1`'s type is `Widget`.

Type of `myWidget2`:

> error: invalid use of incomplete type `struct TD<const Widget&>`

So its type is indeed `const Widget &`, as you suspected.

So yes, what you've described is right.